# How can I update a jsonb column while leaving existing fields intact in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, jsonb

How can I refactor this update statement so that it updates a jsonb column in my postgresql table?

```
    update contacts as c set latitude = v.latitude,longitude = v.longitude,
    home_house_num = v.home_house_num,home_predirection = v.home_predirection,
home_street_name = v.home_street_name, home_street_type = v.home_street_type
    from (values (16247746,40.814140,-74.259250,'25',null,'Moran','Rd'),
          (16247747,20.900840,-156.373700,'581','South','Pili Loko','St')) 
as v(contact_id,latitude,longitude,home_house_num,home_predirection,home_street_name,home_street_type) where c.contact_id = v.contact_id
```

My table looks like this ...

```
|contact_id (bigInt) |data (jsonb)|
-----------------------------------
|111231              |{"email": "albsmith@gmail.com", "home_zip": "07052", "lastname": "Smith",
                       "firstname": "Al", "home_phone": "1111111111", "middlename": "B",
                       "home_address1": "25 Moran Rd", "home_street_name": "Moran Rd"}
```

Note that I do not want to overwrite any other fields that may already exist in the jsonb object that are not specified in the update statement. For example, in this example, I would not want to overwrite the email or name fields

Answer (score 0):

You could restructure your update into something like:

```
update
    contacts c
set
    data = c.data || v.data
FROM
    (values
        (
            16247746,
            '{
                "latitude": 40.814140,
                "longitude": -74.259250,
                "home_house_num": "25",
                "home_predirection": null,
                "home_street_name": "Moran",
                "home_street_type": "Rd"
            }'::JSONB
        ),
        (
            16247747,
            '{
                "latitude": 20.900840,
                "longitude": -156.373700,
                "home_house_num": "581",
                "home_predirection": "Sourth",
                "home_street_name": "Pili Loko",
                "home_street_type": "St"
            }'::JSONB
        )
    ) as v(
        contact_id,
        data
    )
where
    c.contact_id = v.contact_id
;
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, this seems like a good start. Now how can I update multiple rows in a single query?

Comment: Linking another great answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63332234/text-and-jsonb-concatenation-in-a-single-postgresql-query/63332294?noredirect=1#comment111988918_63332294