# Text and jsonb concatenation in a single postgresql query

Tags: postgresql, concatenation, jsonb

How can I concatenate a string inside of a concatenated jsonb object in postgresql? In other words, I am using the JSONb concatenate operator as well as the text concatenate operator in the same query and running into trouble.

Or... if there is a totally different query I should be executing, I'd appreciate hearing suggestions. The goal is to update a row containing a jsonb column. We don't want to overwrite existing key value pairs in the jsonb column that are not provided in the query and we also want to update multiple rows at once.

My query:

```
update contacts as c set data = data || '{"geomatch": "MATCH","latitude":'||v.latitude||'}'
from (values (16247746,40.814140),
      (16247747,20.900840),
      (16247748,20.890570)) as v(contact_id,latitude) where c.contact_id = v.contact_id
```

The Error:

```
 ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
    LINE 85: update contacts as c set data = data || '{"geomatch": "MATCH...
                                                     ^
    DETAIL:  The input string ended unexpectedly.
    CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: {"geomatch": "MATCH","latitude":
    SQL state: 22P02
    Character: 4573
```

Comment: I think all I need to do is add parenthesis around the text like this...data || ('{"geomatch": "MATCH","latitude":'||v.latitude||'}')::jsonb  This seems to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be looking for

```
SET data = data || ('{"geomatch": "MATCH","latitude":'||v.latitude||'}')::jsonb
--              ^^ jsonb                              ^^ text     ^^ text
```

but that's not how one should build JSON objects - that `v.latitude` might not be a valid JSON literal, or even contain some injection like `"", "otherKey": "oops"`. (Admittedly, in your example you control the values, and they're numbers so it might be fine, but it's still a bad practice). Instead, use [`jsonb_build_object`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE):

```
SET data = data || jsonb_build_object('geomatch', 'MATCH', 'latitude', v.latitude)
```

Comment: Okay, thank you. How would this example look in the recommended approach with jsonb_build_object? Perhaps like this?  update contacts as c set data = data || jsonb_build_object('geomatch','MATCH','latitude',v.latitude) from (values(16247746,40.814140),
   (16247747,20.900840),
   (16247748,20.890570)) as v(contact_id,latitude) where c.contact_id = v.contact_id

Comment: @GNG Yes, like that :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems.  The first is operator precedence preventing your concatenation of a `jsonb` object to what is read a `text` object.  The second is that the concatenation of `text` pieces requires a cast to `jsonb`.

This should work:

```
update contacts as c 
   set data = data || ('{"geomatch": "MATCH","latitude":'||v.latitude||'}')::jsonb
  from (values (16247746,40.814140),
               (16247747,20.900840),
               (16247748,20.890570)) as v(contact_id,latitude) 
 where c.contact_id = v.contact_id
;
```